# Как написать скрипт который вычитывает из файла список временных значений и выводит на экран этот же список, но в отсортированном виде

Tags: php, дата

Как написать скрипт который вычитывает из файла список временных значений и выводит на экран этот же список, но в отсортированном виде

Например, вычитав строку 23:45:54 15:35:09 04:18:00 18:08:43

Она должна вывестись как 23:45:54 18:08:43 15:35:09 04:18:00

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158726/php-compare-time

Comment: как выглядит ваш файл то ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если структура текст-файла такая

```
23:45:54
15:35:09
04:18:00
18:08:43
```

то можно воспользоваться функцией сортировки массивов *rsort()* 
Например:

```
<?php

$file = 'base.txt';
$time = file_exists($file) ? file($file) : [];
rsort($time);
echo join('<br />', $time);
/* Результат:
23:45:54 
18:08:43 
15:35:09 
04:18:00 
*/
```